# Match CJK extension B in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, regex, unicode, cjk

I'm having trouble trying to match CJK extension B characters in a `NSString`.

**[Wikipédia CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B :](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_B)**

> CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B is a Unicode block containing rare
>   and historic CJK ideographs for Chinese, Japanese, Korean, and
>   Vietnamese.

The unicode block of the characters is : from `U+20000` to `U+2A6DF`
I'm using the regex : `[\\ud840-\\ud868][\\udc00-\\udfff]|\\ud869[\\udc00-\\uded6]`to match CJK extension B characters.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *searchedString = @""; // First character (U+20000) 

NSString *pattern = @"[\\ud840-\\ud868][\\udc00-\\udfff]|\\ud869[\\udc00-\\uded6]";

 NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
if ([regex numberOfMatchesInString:searchedString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length])] > 0) {
    NSLog(@"matches");
} else {
    NSLog(@"doesn't match");
}
```

Output : `doesn't match`

For exemple, if I try something more simple for a Hiragana character it is working:

```
NSString *searchedString = @"ひ";

NSString *pattern = @"[\\u3040-\\u309F]";
```

Output : `matches`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your pattern is invalid. The non-capturing group syntax is `(?:...)`. Also, the `g` at the end stands for a literal letter `g` - is it intended?

Comment: Is it possible that it's not working because the values are in `UTF-16` and not `UTF-8` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I accidentally erased the (?:.. part when I formatted my message. To make it simpler, I updated my question

Comment: What about using `\UXXXXXXX` notation? Try `NSString *pattern = @"[\\U00020000-\\U0002A6DF]+";`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot, it works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `\Uxxxxxxxx` notation to match those Unicode characters outside the BMP plane.

Acc. to [ICU regex docs](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp):

> `\Uhhhhhhhh`      Match the character with the hex value `hhhhhhhh`. Exactly eight hex digits must be provided, even though the largest Unicode code point is `\U0010ffff`.

So, use

```
NSString *pattern = @"[\\U00020000-\\U0002A6DF]+";
```

See the [online Obj-C demo](https://ideone.com/ymNLWE)